# Postgres psql select result doesn't list all columns and selecting a column says it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Database: postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)**

```
user@my-machine:~$ psql -U gogs -h localhost -W
Password for user gogs: 
psql (10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

gogs=> \l
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 gogs      | gogs     | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

gogs=> \c gogs
Password for user gogs: 
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
You are now connected to database "gogs" as user "gogs".
gogs=> select * from user
gogs-> ;
 user 
------
 gogs
(1 row)
```

Can anybody please explain why the query is not showing up all the columns in the query result because listing columns I can see there are lot of columns in user table:

```
gogs=> \d+ user
                                                               Table "public.user"
        Column        |          Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default              | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                   | bigint                  |           | not null | nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 lower_name           | character varying(255)  |           | not null |                                  | extended |              | 
 name                 | character varying(255)  |           | not null |                                  | extended |              | 
 full_name            | character varying(255)  |           |          |                                  | extended |              | 
 email                | character varying(255)  |           | not null |                                  | extended |              | 
 passwd               | character varying(255)  |           | not null |                                  | extended |              | 
 login_source         | bigint                  |           | not null | 0                                | plain    |              | 
 login_name           | character varying(255)  |           |          |                                  | extended |              | 
 type                 | integer                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 location             | character varying(255)  |           |          |                                  | extended |              | 
 website              | character varying(255)  |           |          |                                  | extended |              | 
 rands                | character varying(10)   |           |          |                                  | extended |              | 
 salt                 | character varying(10)   |           |          |                                  | extended |              | 
 created_unix         | bigint                  |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 updated_unix         | bigint                  |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 last_repo_visibility | boolean                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 max_repo_creation    | integer                 |           | not null | '-1'::integer                    | plain    |              | 
 is_active            | boolean                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 is_admin             | boolean                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 allow_git_hook       | boolean                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 allow_import_local   | boolean                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 prohibit_login       | boolean                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 avatar               | character varying(2048) |           | not null |                                  | extended |              | 
 avatar_email         | character varying(255)  |           | not null |                                  | extended |              | 
 use_custom_avatar    | boolean                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 num_followers        | integer                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 num_following        | integer                 |           | not null | 0                                | plain    |              | 
 num_stars            | integer                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 num_repos            | integer                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 description          | character varying(255)  |           |          |                                  | extended |              | 
 num_teams            | integer                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
 num_members          | integer                 |           |          |                                  | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "UQE_user_lower_name" UNIQUE, btree (lower_name)
    "UQE_user_name" UNIQUE, btree (name)
```

Also when I try to select a column like

```
gogs=> select email from user;
```

I get error

```
ERROR:  column "email" does not exist
LINE 1: select email from user;
```

Note that I also tried following with no success

```
select "email" from user;
select "Email" from user;
select "EMAIL" from user;
```

This is really puzzling. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selecting from `user` will return your username.  In order to select from a table of that name, you need to prefix it with the schema name, and in this case it is public.  So you will need to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM public.user;
```